# Java Inheritance - are inherited variables "copied" or cached by Child Class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am curious why the last two prints generated different value?

```js
class A {
    int i = 1212;
}

class B extends A {
    A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class MainClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();

        B b = new B(a);

        System.out.println(a.i);

        System.out.println(b.i);

        System.out.println(b.a.i);

        b.a.i = 2121; 
        
        System.out.println("--------");

        System.out.println(a.i); // 2121 ??

        System.out.println(b.i); // 1212 ??
    }
}
```

When I set "i" like this:

```js
 b.a.i = 2121;
```

I am accessing the same reference, it means the same Object A? Object A is created only once, so how is possible to set the variable on the object and get different result depends on the way how I access this value?

UPDATE:
Debug variables in IntelliJ
[image: Debug snapshot]

In IDE it seems that class B has it's own copy of "i" that is of course untouched by changing it via "b.a.i" because the change was made on the A object. Can you please arguing against this assumption because it is still in my head and IDE debug show to me that on the Object "b" there is an "i" variable.

Comment: Note that you are combining two different concepts, `B` *is* an `A`, but also *has* an `A`. I cannot think of a good use case where I would combine these two.

Comment: To concisely answer your `???? 2121` comment directly, the statement `B b = new B(a);` stores the reference to `a` into the member variable a, but also creates a new instance of A as its super.

Comment: I added debug snapshot from IDE. Can you please tell me if I understand it correct or the IDE does not show correctly the reality of the process accessing the "i" variable?

Answer (score 2):

Here the declaration of B is referring to A's object in two different way

1. inheriting A directly.
2. storing A as a property.

So B is having two different A.

Question #1: are you referring to the same A as inheriting?

Answer: no, by `b.a.i` you are not referring to the inheriting A, you are simply referring to property A

object A is created once this is true partially, actually you are creating another A by creating object of B.

To refer to the inheriting A you must use `b.i`

Answer (score 1):

The Think is, int i = 1212 is the default value of all instances of A or it's children
when you modified the value for b, you modifies it only for that instance. So the other instances keeps it's default value.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to point out is that it is not typical to *extend* a class, and then create a reference to that class inside the child class.

When class B extends class A, that means that class B already has **int i = 1212;**. When you extend a class, you are essentially building on top of it.

So in your case, when you create a new **A** object, i = 1212. And then you create a new **B object** and pass in **a**, however, because class B extends A, it already has a variable called **i** that equals 1212.

Your print statements make sense:

- **a.i** will be equal to 1212 because that is what the value is set to in Class A.
- **b.i** will be equal to 1212 because *B extends A* and will inherit the variable **i** from Class A.
- **b.a.i** will be equal to 1212 initially because you 1.) created an A object ***a***, 2.) created a B object ***b*** that has it's own A Object variable that you set to ***a***.
- When you call **b.a.i = 2121**, you are setting your B object's variable ***a*** to have an ***i*** value of 2121. But remember that the object reference in your B object points to the *first* A object you created. Both ***a*** and ***b.a*** point to the same object in memory.